# UnityとVisualStudioの提携がうまくいかない

Tags: unity3d, visual-studio

UnityとVisualStudioを提携させたいです。

Unityのほうで、PreferencesのExtermal Script EditorはVisualStudio2022になっているし、VisualStudioのほうでも拡張機能を入れています。
また、PackageManagerのVisualStudioEditorは最新の状態になっています。
しかし、MonoBehaviourの色が変わらなかったり、入力補完、デバッグができません。
VisualStudioの上のところにUnityにアタッチと出ているので、認識はしていそうです。

これまでに行った対処法として、再ダウンロードと過去バージョンのダウンロードがあります。
再ダウンロードに効果はなく、UnityとVisualStudioのバージョンをそれぞれv2021とv2019にしたり、それぞれの組み合わせを変えてみたときに一瞬だけうまく提携できましたが、次開いた時にはまた提携されていない状態になっていました。
どうすればいいでしょうか？ネットで症状を調べてみても同じ症状の人はいなく、情報がないです。よろしくお願いします。

Unityのバージョンは2022.3.21f1、VisualStudioのほうは2022、PCはWindows11です。

追記
返信でいただいたものを確認してみましたが、すべてあっていそうでした。
またVisualStudioをUnityで起動しようとすると、Windowsセキュリティから、
「このアプリの一部がブロックされています。
Microsoft Visual Studio 2022はSmart App Control のセキュリティ要件を満たしていない MSBuild.exe を読み込もうとしました。」と言われます。もしこれが原因だったら対処法を教えてほしいです。

追記その2
解決しました。追記でブロックされていたSmart App Controlを手動でOFFに変更したところ、しっかりと提携されるようになりました。どうやらSmart App ControlがONになっていると提携がうまくいかなくなるようです。回答ありがとうございました。これからわからないことがあったら聞きに来ると思いますので、その時はお願いします。

Comment: 解決した場合には質問に追記するのではなく、役に立った回答を承認するか、解決に至った情報をご自身で回答として投稿してください。 参考ヘルプ: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

私は、同様の環境で問題なく Unity と Visual Studio 2022 の連携ができています。

以下を確認し、Visual Studio Tools for Unity が正しくインストールできているかを確認ください。

- https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/gamedev/unity/get-started/getting-started-with-visual-studio-tools-for-unity

また、Visual Studio Installer で最新版が適用されていることを確認してみてください。